# Error while integrating firebase to android studio

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, progressive-web-apps

i am trying to integrate firebase to my android project but constantly getting error of 
"In project 'app' a resolved Google Play services library dependency depends on another at an exact version (e.g. "[17.0.
4]", but isn't being resolved to that version. Behavior exhibited by the library will be unknown.

Dependency failing: com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.4 -> com.google.firebase:firebase-iid@[17.0.4], but fire
base-iid version was 20.0.2."

my code for the app gradle build is-------

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.goldfish"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'),
 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    packagingOptions {
        // Exclude file to avoid
        // Error: Duplicate files during packaging of APK
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
        exclude 'META-INF/services/javax.annotation.processing.Processor'
    }

}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.4"
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.2.2'


}
```

Comment: Share your project level gradle

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Upgrade to the [latest versions](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android) of the Firebase libraries:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.1.5'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.3.0'
```